# What is "Bourbaki's style in mathematics"?

Tags: math-history, big-picture

I know [Nicolas Bourbaki](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Bourbaki.html) "is the pseudonym of a group of (mainly) French mathematicians who publish an authoritative account of contemporary mathematics." But what characterizes "Bourbaki's style in mathematics"?

Comment: A lot of what characterizes the "Bourbaki" style is their stringent adherence to definition/theorem/proof/definition/theorem/proof ... writing. Very few if any examples. Everything as general as possible. Very little or no motivation for why you're doing what you're doing.

Comment: It comes from an assumption (wrongheaded IMHO ) that knowledge and understanding build up/develop naturally ( or can be developed naturally) in a strictly bottom-up format.

Comment: Probably also avoiding pictures and geometrical understanding.

Comment: @Geremia: Have you read , e.g,:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki ? I agree with Joh Ntravolta, BTW.

Comment: @user99680: No, I haven't. thanks

Comment: They invented the terms injective, surjective, and bijective? interesting

Comment: As I remember their ambition was to write an Encyclopedia of Mathematics. Their style was probably influenced by this.

Comment: As you can see from Wiki's entry, the treatis *Éléments de mathématique* contains about 30 volumes: it is aimed at "building" all "modern" math on an axiomatic basis.

Comment: It's not listed among references on Wikipedia - that's why I add this reference - I think it may help understanding (read it a long time a go): J. DIEUDONNÉ, The work of Nicholas Bourbaki, Amer.Math. Monthly 77 (1970), 134–145

Comment: You can see two papers from Leo Corry : *Writing the Ultimate Mathematical Textbook : Nicolas Bourbaki’s Éléments de mathématique* and *Nicolas Bourbaki and the Concept of Mathematical Structure*.

Comment: This makes for an interesting read: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/bourbaki.pdf

Comment: Is there a word for "anti-Bourbaki style in math"?

Comment: Summary of math data? = Bourbaki?

Comment: 1/2: "During the 20th century, it became the standard to build mathematical theories on axiomatic set theory. The creation of axiomatically founded generalized theories, such as the general topology, served among other things to single out the common structural core for various specific cases or regions and then set up an abstract theory, which contained all these parts as special cases. This brought a great success in the form of simplification and harmonization and ultimately brought on economy of thought with itself. Hausdorff himself highlighted this aspect in the Principles."

Comment: 2/2: [Felix Hausdorff: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Hausdorff#The_%22Magnum_Opus%22:_%22Principles_of_set_theory%22) Related: Euclid

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Leo Corry, [Writing the Ultimate Mathematical Textbook : Nicolas Bourbaki’s Éléments de mathématique](http://www.tau.ac.il/~corry/publications/articles/pdf/Bourbaki%20-%20OHHM.pdf) :

> In the decades following the founding of the group, Bourbaki’s books became classic in many areas of pure mathematics in which the concepts and main problems, the nomenclature and the peculiar style introduced by Bourbaki were adopted as standard.
>
> The branches upon which Bourbaki exerted the deepest influence were algebra, topology and functional analysis and they became the backbone of mathematical curricula and research activity in many places around the world.
>
> Notations such as the symbol ∅ for the empty set, and terms like *injective*, *surjective*, and *bijective* owe their widespread use to their adoption in the *Éléments de mathématique*.

And :

> Bourbaki’s extremely austere and idiosyncratic presentation of the topics discussed in each of the chapters – from which diagrams and external motivations were expressly excluded – became a hallmark of the group’s style and a main manifestation of its thorough influence.
>
> Also the widespread adoption of approaches to specific question, concepts, and nomenclature promoted in the books of the series indicate the breadth of this influence.
>
> Concepts and theories were presented in a thoroughly axiomatic way and systematically discussed always going from the more general to the particular, and never generalizing a particular result.

And :

> In 1950 Dieudonné published, signing with the name of Bourbaki, an article that came to be
>   identified as the group’s manifesto, “The Architecture of Mathematics”. Faced with the
>   unprecedented growth and diversification of knowledge in the discipline over the preceding
>   decades, Dieudonné raised once again the well-known question of the unity of mathematics.
>
> Mathematics is a strongly unified branch of knowledge in spite of appearances, he claimed, and now it is clear that the basis of this unity is the use of the axiomatic method as the work of David Hilbert had clearly revealed starting from the beginning of the century.
>
> Mathematics should be seen, Dieudonné added, as a hierarchy of structures at the heart of which lie the so called “mother structures”:
>
> > At the center of our universe are found the great types of structures, ... they might be called the mother structures ... Beyond this first nucleus, appear the structures which might be called multiple structures. They involve two or more of the great mother-structures not in simple juxtaposition (which would not produce anything new) but combined organically by one or more axioms which set up a connection between them... Farther along we come finally to the theories properly called particular.

In additon to Leo Corry's papers, cab be useful also his book :

> Leo Corry, [Modern Algebra and the Rise of Mathematical Structures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3764370025) (2nd ed - 2003).

Comment: Nice quotes. While you are at it you could add Corry's comments on Bourbaki's blocking of Groethendieck's attempt to publish a volume on algebraic infinitesimals.

Comment: @user72694 - The "massive effort" of Bourbaki's systhematization achieved a "landmark" in the shaping of modern math; of course, it had also an aspect of "dogmatism" : what was "outside" Bourbaki's framework was descouraged...

Comment: Precisely, with one of the larger things that were "outside" being category theory, as Corry discusses in detail.

Comment: Is it fair to say "Bourbaki's style" is heavily deductive whereas "[Russian style](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1993299/128568)" is inductive?

Comment: @Geremia - I do not think so... maybe Russian math is more interested to application (to e.g. physiscs) while Bourbaki's one is more "abstract".