# What is "Russian-style" mathematics?

Tags: math-history

I've just stumbled upon Gorodentsev's upcoming textbook '[Algebra I](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319452845)'.
The description of it claims that it's very 'Russian-style'.

> This book is the first volume of an intensive “Russian-style” two-year graduate course in abstract algebra, and introduces readers to the basic algebraic structures – fields, rings, modules, algebras, groups, and categories – and explains the main principles of and methods for working with them.

What does this mean? What differs 'Russian-style' from 'American-style' mathematics?

Comment: This is a guess, but it sounds like something akin to a style of rigor perhaps employed at Russian universities. You could perhaps read up on math and science education in the time of the Soviet Union.

Comment: One might view "Russian style" as "math that skips steps."  It can be intimidating since the steps that are skipped are implicitly viewed as being "obvious."

Comment: I would understand it as _elitist and intellectually demanding_, the kind of course that aims at pushing the smartest 10% of the class as far as they can be pushed, even at the cost of failing 80% -- whereas a stereotypically "American-style" course would aim at making as many students as possible _pass_, even at the cost of the 10% brightest only learning a tenth of what they _could_ have achieved in a course tailored for them.

Comment: Kolmogorov, Chebyshev, Markov, Lusin, Suslin, Egorov, Khinchin, Vinogradov, Pontryagin, ... are all great Russian mathematicians; perhaps their works would speak for Russian style. :)

Comment: The springer page also states "Challenging amount of material thoughtfully organized for deep and fast learning" maybe this is what is meant.

Comment: What is "American style"?

Answer (score 20):

*Russian-style* should be understood not in opposition to *American-style* (that's cold war stuff) but rather in opposition to French-style or more precisely *Bourbaki-style*.  The latter emphasizes formalism even sometimes at the expense of readability.  The Russian style tends to focus on the essence rather than the formalism, and emphasize what is novel. A good example of accessible, popular, and rigorous writing in the Russian-style is a typical book by [Vladimir Arnold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Arnold); for example, his *Mathematical methods of classical mechanics*, an all-time favorite.

The flip side of excessive formalism is often committing *errors*; this was richly illustrated in the case of Bourbaki by Adrian Mathias; see e.g., his
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03025863 .

Comment: *"To the question "what is 2 + 3" a French primary school pupil replied: "3 + 2, since addition is commutative". He did not know what the sum was equal to and could not even understand what he was asked about!"* — V. I. Arnold (in [On teaching mathematics](http://pauli.uni-muenster.de/~munsteg/arnold.html))

Comment: Well this particular story doesn't go very far because a certain French mathematician stepped forward at MathOverflow and claimed that *he* was that child, and he meant it as a joke, so Arnold may have overused that example. At any rate the calamities of Bourbaki style are well-known and have recently been critiqued by Mathias; see e.g. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03025863 @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: @MikhailKatz I (and I think everybody else) would be interested in what the French mathematician said; could you provide the link?. Googling didn't yield any results.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153604/the-arnold-serre-debate/153606#comment393855_153606 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153604/the-arnold-serre-debate/153606#comment393860_153606

Comment: How can a textbook claim to be for aspiring mathematicians and not be written in Bourbaki-Style? I thought formalism was the whole point of mathematics.

Comment: @ClassicEndingMusic, as a professional mathematician I hurry to disabuse you of the notion that Bourbaki-style is obligatory or for that matter desirable; but perhaps this is a subject for a separate *question*.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Now I am intrigued. I will read Bourbaki's Elements of Mathemtics II Algebra and afterwards Gorodentsev's book. Let's see how this compares.

Comment: Is it fair to say "Russian style" is inductive whereas "[Bourbaki's style](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/792063/128568)" is deductive?

Comment: And what exactly is "American style"?