# Bourbaki influence on the current mathematical research

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, philosophy, research

I know that the bourbakism had an influence in the academic world and an impact in secondary school and university. There are remarks in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki) dedicated to Nicolas Bourbaki.

> **Question.** Does Nicolas Bourbaki have an influence on the current mathematical  research? In what branchs/fields of mathematics, and why? Feel free if you need it to answer this as a reference request, and I try to find and read those facts. **Many thanks.**

I am asking from an informative point of view.

Comment: Current research: probably not. "Influence in the academic world [and school]": not only. See the post [what-is-the-legacy-of-Bourbaki](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144865/what-is-the-legacy-of-bourbaki) as well as [what-is-Bourbaki's-style-in-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792063/what-is-bourbakis-style-in-mathematics).

Comment: Many thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA , I am going to see your references. I am asking about the influence on the current research. Maybe some user can say something about it. And I am seeing that you know about it a lot.

Comment: For the historical side (but we speak of a very recent history: so its relevance for current math is quite high), the best indirect source is: Leo Corry, [Modern Algebra and the Rise of Mathematical Structures](https://books.google.it/books?id=8G0FCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1). See also: L.Corry, [Nicolas Bourbaki and the concept of mathematical structure](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00414286).

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and help about this question @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: I would say that part of their influence is that people are somewhat afraid of set theory and logic. The Bourbaki presentation is just horrible... And there are people who barely get exposed to proper introduction to logic.

Comment: @asaf-karagila You are absolutely right. Jacques Herbrand's premature death was a disaster in this regard.

Comment: Many thanks @AsafKaragila I see in comments and the literature that there are two points of view about bourbakism.

Comment: Many thanks for the edit @MikhailKatz . And if some user want do more feedbak about this question it is welcome.

Comment: @user243301: Mikhail Katz had created the bourbaki tag a couple year back. It was discussed on the meta site, and the majority of support was that the tag is unneeded. It seems that Mr. Katz had forgotten that. Other than bumping the question to the main page, there is nothing to thank him for.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I consider the work that did any user in my posts. Any case my apologizes to you and all users since I think that this my question isn't the best: the problem is that in the past I've read about the important impact/influence of Bourbaki in the academic/education world and I wanted to ask here this question as a companion question, what about of the impact of Bourbaki in the current research. Today I feel that this question isn't the best.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main influence on current research of Bourbaki seems to be the [Bourbaki Seminar](http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr). Here is a [link](http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr/seminaires/2018/Prog_janv18.html) to the program of the next seminar, on January 13, 2018.

Comment: This is obviously wrong. The main influence on current mathematical research might more likely lie in a general ethos of precision and rigour.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Did I am not sure that Bourbaki, who is indeed fond of precision and rigor, would endorse your sentence "This is obviously wrong" for an unproved statement, mostly opinion based.

Comment: Don't you think you are the one who ought to provide concrete elements to support the outlandish idea that a mere seminar is the main influence of Bourbaki on research today? (Yes, yes, I know, this is not quite a standard seminar, but yet!) Or is this a veiled way of saying that this influence is, overall, nearly zero?